# Loading data into json file

Tags: javascript, sapui5

How can i update json file from model in sap ui5?

```
    var oModel  = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.loadData("json/Product.json");
```

I have to update my product.json file.
Please give me your suggestion...

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: do you mean you change the model and need to save the modified one to the file again?

Comment: @Matthias : Yes, i want to modify the model and then update the json file again.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update a JSON file stored on your server with UI5 or any client side library. You will need a server-side script with some file writing code to do it. You should use an OData service and perform any read/write operations to it.